# Multiple structures in a single malloc invoking undefined behaviour?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c89, flexible-array-member

From [Use the correct syntax when declaring a flexible array member](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/DCL38-C.+Use+the+correct+syntax+when+declaring+a+flexible+array+member) it says that when `malloc` is used for a header and flexible data when `data[1]` is hacked into the `struct`,

> This example has undefined behavior when accessing any element other
>   than the first element of the data array. (See the C Standard, 6.5.6.)
>   Consequently, the compiler can generate code that does not return the
>   expected value when accessing the second element of data.

I looked up the C Standard 6.5.6, and could not see how this would produce undefined behaviour. I've used a pattern that I'm comfortable with, where the header is implicitly followed by data, using the same sort of `malloc`,

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* EXIT malloc free */
#include <stdio.h>  /* printf */
#include <string.h> /* strlen memcpy */

struct Array {
    size_t length;
    char *array;
}; /* +(length + 1) char */

static struct Array *Array(const char *const str) {
    struct Array *a;
    size_t length;
    length = strlen(str);
    if(!(a = malloc(sizeof *a + length + 1))) return 0;
    a->length = length;
    a->array = (char *)(a + 1); /* UB? */
    memcpy(a->array, str, length + 1);
    return a;
}

/* Take a char off the end just so that it's useful. */
static void Array_to_string(const struct Array *const a, char (*const s)[12]) {
    const int n = a->length ? a->length > 9 ? 9 : (int)a->length - 1 : 0;
    sprintf(*s, "<%.*s>", n, a->array);
}

int main(void) {
    struct Array *a = 0, *b = 0;
    int is_done = 0;
    do { /* Try. */
        char s[12], t[12];
        if(!(a = Array("Foo!")) || !(b = Array("To be or not to be."))) break;
        Array_to_string(a, &s);
        Array_to_string(b, &t);
        printf("%s %s\n", s, t);
        is_done = 1;
    } while(0); if(!is_done) {
        perror(":(");
    } {
        free(a);
        free(b);
    }
    return is_done ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Prints,

```
<Foo> <To be or >
```

The compliant solution uses `C99` flexible array members. The page also says,

> Failing to use the correct syntax when declaring a flexible array
>   member can result in undefined behavior, although the incorrect syntax
>   will work on most implementations.

Technically, does this `C90` code produce undefined behaviour, too? And if not, what is the difference? (Or the Carnegie Mellon Wiki is incorrect?) What is the factor on the implementations this will not work on?

Comment: Note: "accessing the second element of data." --> There is no 2nd element (of type `struct Array`) of an _array_ here.  "other than the first element of the data array" does not apply as there is no _array_.  I see no UB here,

Comment: True, I could have a `char [1]` on the end of `Array`; does that matter very much?

Comment: The UB is asserted to be due to invalid array usage.  Without an array, it is hard to support a UB claim due to that,

Comment: Having `char [1]` on the end of `Array` changes the type of `struct Array`, yet there is still no `struct Array` _array_ here.  `struct Array foo[1]`; is an _array_.  `struct Array *a;` is a pointer.

Comment: @chux Pointer arithmetic on a non-array object behaves as if it was an array of length 1 as per 6.5.6p7.

Comment: The UB of the quote "This example has undefined behavior..."` is not of posted code, but of the linked "Use the correct syntax...".  In that code, there is array access outside array bounds.  I guess I do not see how this non-comparable code is suppose to have UB.

Comment: @dbush Yes, no news on [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55014685/multiple-structures-in-a-single-malloc-invoking-undefined-behaviour?noredirect=1#comment96784136_55014685) - how do you see that relevant to somehow considering OP's code UB?

Comment: IMO, the mistake is asserting this code is alike enough to the referenced code (which has UB) and then incorrectly inferring this code also has UB.  Perhaps I am simply missing OP's point.

Comment: So the UB is due to having an index-out-of-bounds?

Comment: @chux Actually, I think the pointer arithmetic is OK in this case.  There are potential alignment issues however.

Comment: In the linked example, yes, UB due to index-out-of-bounds

Comment: @dbush In OP's case, no alignment issues with `char`, yet as per your good answer, possible with various other types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be well defined:

```
a->array = (char *)(a + 1);
```

Because you create a pointer to one element past the end of an array of size 1 but do not dereference it.  And because `a->array` now points to bytes that do not yet have an effective type, you can use them safely.

This only works however because you're using the bytes that follow as an array of `char`.  If you instead tried to create an array of some other type whose size is greater than 1, you could have alignment issues.

For example, if you compiled a program for ARM with 32 bit pointers and you had this:

```
struct Array {
    int size;
    uint64_t *a;
};
...
Array a = malloc(sizeof *a + (length * sizeof(uint64_t)));
a->length = length;
a->a= (uint64_t *)(a + 1);       // misaligned pointer
a->a[0] = 0x1111222233334444ULL;  // misaligned write
```

Your program would crash due to a misaligned write.  So in general you shouldn't depend on this.  Best to stick with a flexible array member which the standard guarantees will work.

Comment: Is there any way to align an array so that this would work? Just put more data in `Array`?

Comment: @NeilEdelman You would need to determine the alignment requirements of the struct and the alignment requirement of the pointed-to type.  If the former is less, then you need to round up to the next multiple of the latter and point there.

Comment: Effective type didn't exist in C90 though.

Answer (score 2):

As an adjunct to [@dbush](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55014974/2410359) good answer, a way to get around alignment woes is to use a `union`. This insures `&p[1]` is properly aligned for `(uint64_t*)`<sup>1</sup>.  `sizeof *p` includes any needed padding vs. `sizeof *a`.

```
  union {
    struct Array header;
    uint64_t dummy;
  } *p;
  p = malloc(sizeof *p + length*sizeof p->header->array);

  struct Array *a = (struct Array *)&p[0]; // or = &(p->header);
  a->length = length;
  a->array = (uint64_t*) &p[1]; // or &p[1].dummy;
```

Or go with C99 and flexible array member.

---

<sup>1</sup> As well as `struct Array`

Comment: Extremely clever!

Answer (score 1):

Before the publication of C89, there were some implementations that would attempt to identify and trap upon out-of-bounds array accesses.  Given something like:

```
struct foo {int a[4],b[4];} *p;
```

such implementations would squawk at an effort to access `p->a[i]` if `i` wasn't in the range 0 to 3.  For programs that don't need to index the address of array-type lvalue `p->a` to access anything outside that array, being able to trap on such out-of-bounds accesses would be useful.

The authors of C89 were also almost certainly aware that it was common for programs to use the address of dummy-sized array at the end of a structure as a means of accessing storage beyond the structure.  Using such techniques made it possible to do things that couldn't be done nearly as nicely otherwise, and part of the Spirit of C, according to the authors of the Standard, is "Don't prevent the programmer from doing what needs to be done".

Consequently, the authors of the Standard treated such accesses as something which implementations could support or not, at their leisure, presumably based upon what would be most useful for their customers.  While it would often be helpful for implementations which would normally bounds-check accesses to structures in an array, to provide an option to omit such checks in cases where the last item of an indirectly-accessed structure is an array with one element (or, if they extend the language to waive a compile-time constraint, zero elements), people writing such implementations would presumably be capable of recognizing such things without the authors of the Standard having to tell them.  The notion that "Undefined Behavior" was intended as some form of prohibition doesn't seem to have really taken hold until after the publication of C89's successor standard.

With regard to your example, having a pointer within a struct point to later storage in the same allocation should work, but with a couple of caveats:

1. If the allocation is passed to `realloc`, the pointer within it will become invalid.
2. The only real advantage of using a pointer versus a flexible array member is that it allows for the possibility of having it point somewhere else.  That may be good if the only kind of "something else" will always be an constant object of static duration that never has to be freed, or perhaps if it is some other kind of object that won't have to be freed, but may be problematical if it could hold the only reference to something stored in a separate allocation.

Flexible array members have been available as an extension in some compilers before C89 was written, and were officially added in C99.  Any decent compiler should support them.

Answer (score 0):

You can define struct `Array` as:

```
struct Array
{
    size_t length;
    char array[1];
}; /* +(length + 1) char */
```

then `malloc( sizeof *a + length )`. The "+1" element is in `array[1]` member. Fill structure with:

```
a->length = length;
strcpy( a->array, str );
```

Comment: That's what the CM Wiki says is undefined behaviour. @chux points out in the comments that it's because the index is out-of-bounds. CM Wiki also says, "although the incorrect syntax will work on most implementations," and rates it, "Unlikely," and says, "This approach may be the only alternative for compilers that do not yet implement the standard C [99] syntax."

Comment: OK but the idea for such implementation is bad. My suggestion is for something similar which uses less memory, without pointer and UB.