# How should I create a linked list with a generic amount of items per node in C

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I need to expand a linked list in C that is able to take a generic number of (same type) values.

Here is the generic linked list:

```
struct Node {
int item;
struct Node* next;
};

struct List {
    struct Node* head;
    struct Node* tail;
};


struct List SLL_new() {
    /* construct an empty list */
    struct List list;
    list.head = NULL;
    list.tail = NULL;
    return list;
}
```

I need to modify SLL_new() to take an integer parameter that represents the number of items that will be stored in a single node.

I could do something like:

```
struct Node {
int item1;
int item2;
int item3;
int item4;
int item5;
struct Node* next;
};
```

but this probably isn't feasible, as there's no limit on the number of items that can be stored in a node. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Make it a pointer to a dynamically-allocated array.

Comment: Could you use an array of items in the node, which is allocated memory? Needing another member say `max_available` and another for say `num_used`.

Comment: A list of lists?

Comment: Please explain why a static array inside `Node` is not an option. I do not get it and it seems so obvious.

Comment: You can have a list with a pointer to an array that you `malloc()` and a `size_t ` struct member that contains the array size and a `uint16_t` struct member  that contains a count of elements like @WeatherVane just pointed out. And you can use `realloc()` as needed to double the size of the array anytime you need exceed the threshold (so you don't do it too often, common `realloc()` technique). Or as Scott Hunter said you can create a list of linked lists and then you have to nest the access and `free()` loops.

Answer (score 4):

Use a struct with a flexible array:

```
struct Node {
  struct Node* next;
  int items[];    
};
```

Now you can initialize each node with `malloc(sizeof(struct Node) + sizeof(int) * n)` and access the members with `node.items[i]`.

**Update**: If you can't use flexible arrays, you can still use this technique. The code changes as follows:

```
struct Node {
  struct Node* next;
};
#define NODE_ACCESS(node, i) (((int*)((node)+1))[i])
```

Now you can access your integers with `NODE_ACCESS(my_node, item_no)`.

Comment: Wasn't that practice deprecated? Can't remember where I read that.

Comment: It wasn't. You're probably thinking of VLAs, but they're something totally different. Flexible Array Structs are actually quite safe to use.

Comment: No, not thinking of VLAs, which are not deprecated, but optional.

Comment: Wikipedia says introduced in C99 and doesn't mention any deprecation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member

Comment: Unfortunately I have to compile it with gcc -Wpedantic, so flexible arrays aren't supported.

Comment: Which language standard are you using? Flexible arrays are perfectly valid C99, so `-Wpedantic` shouldn't have any problem with them (unless if you're on `-std=c89`).

Comment: You can do exactly the same thing with a cast if you really need to, but `-Wpedantic` should still allow it if you're using C99.

Comment: Thanks, the flexible array member is still described in [C18](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf)

Comment: Flexible array members are not supported with `-std=c90`, but from [answers to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55014685/multiple-structures-in-a-single-malloc-invoking-undefined-behaviour), it's fine to not declare it and just use it as long as the alignment is right, (which you can guarantee with a `union` or by including at least one item.)

Answer (score 0):

> I need to modify SLL_new() to take an integer parameter that represents the number of items that will be stored in a single node.

So *do* that. You're not asked how the eventual Node allocation will work yet, you just need

```
struct List {
    int node_elements;
    struct Node* head;
    struct Node* tail;
};

struct List SLL_new(int nelem) {
    /* construct an empty list */
    struct List list;
    list.node_elements = nelem;
    list.head = NULL;
    list.tail = NULL;
    return list;
}
```

Once you've done that, the other answer's flexible array is how you'll actually use `node_elements` every time you allocate a new node in this list.